# Is there any way to keep state between restarting detox

Tags: react-native, detox

i have the authorization in the app and i need to check the screens after sign in. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: do you want to maintain routes of screens / stacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every detox runs, it will reinstall the app. So if you want to continue testing the app without reinstall every runs, you can add `--reuse` flag on detox command. It will reuse installed app on your test device/simulator. You can read more about this on Detox documentation [here](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.Configuration.md#faster-test-runs-with-app-reuse).

Comment: To the OP: make sure to check "behavior" section in Detox config: https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.Configuration.md#behavior-configuration

Also, consider using `device.reloadReactNative()` if that does not cause buggy behavior in your app — that also might save some time.